# Image Float Issues

Tags: css

I need help on the image float on 'Module 5 - 18. CSS Float and Clear'  of Angela's web devt course. I've tried making the skill images float the image of the second skill keeps getting messed up.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried grouping both 'skill' images in a `round` class and used:

```
.round-skill {
  float: left;
}
```

But only the skill image on top worked out as planned. The skill image below and other elements below that (like the footer) went off

```css
.skill-row {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.skill-row-sub {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 2;
}

.skill-row-tab-title {
  text-align: left;
}

.round-skill-1 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
  <h2>My Skills.</h2>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img class="round-skill-1" src="images/avatar.png" alt="">
    <h3 class="skill-row-tab-title">Frontend Development</h3>
    <p class="skill-row-sub">I develop website interface designs using frontend technologies such as HTML and CSS. Still learning Javascript and its frameworks.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img class="round" src="images/avatar.png" alt="">
    <h3>UI/UX</h3>
    <p>I design interfaces using Sketch and Adobe XD</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make both skill images float: left without messing up the layout?

Answer (score 0):

make a div or some tag with class "cls"(usually used), and give it css: 
.cls {clear: both};

place element with this class after :

`<p class="skill-row-sub">I develop website interface designs using frontend technologies such as HTML and CSS. Still learning Javascript and its frameworks.</p>`

it should be okay.

clear: both will separate one float from another

like this:

```
    `<div class="skills">
    <h2>My Skills.</h2>
     <div class="skill-row">
         <img class="round-skill-1" src="images/tree-3097419__340.jpg" alt="">
         <h3 class="skill-row-tab-title">Frontend Development</h3>
         <p class="skill-row-sub">I develop website interface designs using frontend technologies such as HTML and CSS. Still learning Javascript and its frameworks.</p>
         <div class="cls"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="skill-row">
         <img class="round" src="images/tree-3097419__340.jpg" alt="">
         <h3>UI/UX</h3>
         <p>I design interfaces using Sketch and Adobe XD</p>

     </div>
 </div>`
```

css:

```
`.cls {clear: both};`
```

Comment: FWIW, this is an outdated approach to clearing floats. One should not have to add markup for the sole reason of clearing floats. Use a clearfix class instead, use `overflow: hidden;` (if appropriate), or one of many other possible CSS only solutions.